# Passing HTML from ASP.NET MVC controller to browser direct link is not rendering HTML tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My `HelloWorldController`:

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    // GET: /HelloWorld/ 
    public string Index() {
        return "This is my <b>default</b> action...";
    }

    // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 
    public string Welcome() {
        return "This is the Welcome action method...";
    }
}
```

Viewing the page on:
`http://localhost:12121/HelloWorld`

It returns:

```
This is my <b>default</b> action...
```

Why does it not render the bold tags?

Comment: You say you're passing it to your View. What view? There is no view. You're just sending a string.

Comment: Sorry, it's just displaying the string on the page - how do you force it to render the HTML, following an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-a-controller) it rendered it.

Comment: the above should work, how are you calling it ?

Comment: Just from the link in the browser directly to the Index() function to return the string

Comment: you can try this method: `public ActionResult Index() { return Content("This is my <b>default</b> action...", "text/html"); }`

Comment: @Artemis, do a google search on YouTube MVC tutorials there are so many working simple examples and tutorials out there.. take the time to understand the different types of data types etc that can be returned using ActionResult

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that worked, and rendered the HTML - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change the return type to `ActionResult` and then use `Content()` and explicitly specify the content type that is being returned so that browser knows it is html and would render it, right know it is returning as [Html Encoded string](https://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode) so browser wouldn't render it:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{ 
    return Content("This is my <b>default</b> action...", "text/html"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     return Content("This is my <b>default</b> action...");
 }
```

Comment: This didn't solve the issue it still wont render the bold tags.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be passing HTML from controller, you should use cshtml views to render HTML, and rendering different things by passing a model to your view by your controller.

Here is an example of controller method :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel()
    {
        Text = "Hello world"
    };

    return this.View(model);
}
```

Here is an example of cshtml view :

```
@* This is the model you passed, you must pass the correct path to it's class *@
@model MyApp.Models.MyModel

@* This should render the "Hello world" message *@
@Model.Text
```